# Parsing JSON/XML to treeview

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, treeview

I've the following XML file:

```
<Name attrNa=”valueNa1” attrNa2=”valueNa2”>
  value1
  <Name1 attr1=”value3” attr2=”value4”>value2</Name1>
  <Lue attrLu1="valueLu1">value2</Lue>
</Name>
```

I need to parse it to treeview, like the following:

```
Parameter/Attribure Name   Parameter/Atrribute Value

Name                       value1                    
    Name1                  value2
         ()attr1                value3
         ()attr2                value4
    ()attrNa               valueNa1
    ()attrNa2              valueNa2

Lue                        valueLue
    ()attrLu1              valueLu1
```

JSON File:

```
{
  "Name": {
    "-attrNa": "valueNa1",
    "-attrNa2": "valueNa2",
    "#text": "value1",
    "Name1": {
      "-attr1": "value3",
      "-attr2": "value4",
      "#text": "value2"
    },
    "Lue": {
      "-attrLu1": "valueLu1",
      "#text": "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use an open source editJSON (http://mb21.github.io/JSONedit/), I see that isn't good for my requirements, now I decided to develop my own directive, is any one have an idea to start, or any other open source to do that?

Thanks,
Ramzy

Comment: Ramji have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I tried to use an open source (http://mb21.github.io/JSONedit/)

Answer (score 0):

For parsing to tree view you have to use directives. I have implemented the same :

```
$scope.roleList1 = [{"Name":[{"-attrNa":"valueNa1","-attrNa2":"valueNa2","#text":"value1","Name1":[{"-attr1":"value3","-attr2":"value4","#text":"value2"}]}],"Lue":[{"-attrLu1":"valueLu1","#text":"value2"}]}];
```

Plunker:

http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/